# How to print int array which its size is unknown

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say we havew a function that returns an array.

```
int *theFunction()
{
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
return a;
}
```

I want to store the result of the function in a pointer.

```
int *a=theFunction();
```

How do I print the array, is it even possible?
The length of the array isn't known, is there a way to find it?

Comment: In this case, the length is the least of your problems. Your code can't work, because you're returning a pointer to `a`, which is an automatic variable and thus gets destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant print an `array` when its `size` is **unknown**

---

You can get around this problem by

1>providing a **sentinal value** i.e the value that would denote the end of the array.
Let us consider `-1` to be the sentinal then

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,-1};
                    ^
                    |->-1 would denote the end of array
```

But this solution would **fail** if one of your value seems to be `-1`

**OR**

2>Use a **struct** to denote the size and the array content

```
struct list
{
int *values;//the array of values
int size;//size of the values array
}
```

---

Also dont return a pointer to value that has local scope..i.e in your case the local value is `a`..As soon as you get out of the method a is destroyed..further access to this `a` after the method returns is an error

Comment: Or use an abstract data type, which hides the implementation details (the struct) and exposes functions to safely manipulate the array.  [Quick reference](http://cii.s3.amazonaws.com/book/pdf/quickref.pdf) for one implementation by Hanson; [source code](http://code.google.com/p/cii/downloads/list).

Answer (score 4):

No.

You'll need to delineate the array with a value you know won't come up, or pass a pointer to the function which will populate it with the size.

But you're also returning a pointer to data on the stack; that won't work either.

Answer (score 3):

First, never ever return pointers to local variables. Allocate that array on the heap.

As for returning the size of the array, you can have the function return a structure that contains both the pointer and the array size.

Another method is to have the caller pass a reference to a size variable that the callee modifies.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a local variable, you can't acceed to its value out of `theFunction` function.

Anyway, to print an array without its size, you have to add a delimiter (a particular value, for instance).

Comment: Not true, it returns a pointer to static data, which is valid outside of the function.

Comment: @AxelGneiting How do you get that?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's the data that you initialize with that is compile time static, and therefore will be in the data section at a static place.

Comment: @AxelGneiting I thought that that data was in the string literals section and copied to the stack ...

Comment: What is copied to the stack is the address to it (variable a), not the data itself.

Comment: @AxelGneiting sure? I think that room is created on stack, enough to copy the static data, the data are then copied, and `a` is the pointer to the local data (on stack), and so it is wrong to give it back. And so, `a[0] = 5` is valid, while if it is as you say (`a` pointing to "static literal storage"), it could give an access error.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Check the disassembly.

Comment: no, it sounds like "it works on my machine". What we need to check is what the language specs say.

Comment: There is no copy involved. That line is essentially nothing more than a pointer assignment. It's the same than for strings. `return "foo"` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AxelGneiting: Sorry but you are completely wrong. The lifetime of the `a[]` array is limited to the function body. It is _always_ an error to return a pointer to local temporary variables. Note that your `return "foo"` example has nothing to do with the code in the question.

Comment: @AxelGneiting a) "badRet.c:4:1: warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]", b) `movl    $1, -32(%rbp)` etc. There is no static array produced by gcc here, the array is allocated on the stack and filled with immediate values.

Answer (score 1):

How hard it is to also return the length of the array as an out param? 
If you have any special number in the array that marks the end, you could use that. **Otherwise there is no way you can find the length of the array just with a pointer.** And about returning a stack pointer outside the function, it may lead to crash.